# Kubuntu 15.04 dist-upgrade failing

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I've just installed Kubuntu 15.04 and added the Kubuntu CI PPA (to get Plasma 5.4) but when I type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kio_5.15.0+git20151011.0307+15.04-0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/kio_5.15.0+git20151011.0307+15.04-0_amd64.deb`